# How to add items of LazyColumn inside a Card or any other view?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

When I am trying to add a card over items then this error is shown ***@Composable invocations can only happen from the context of a @Composable function***

```
@Composable
fun ReceiptsListing() {
    val mappedReceipts = receipts.groupBy { DateUtils.humanizeDatetime(context, locale, it.uploadDate.dateToLocalDateTime())}
    val listState = rememberLazyListState()
    val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()
    LazyColumn( state = listState,
        modifier = Modifier
            .padding(horizontal = 16.dp)
            .padding(top = 70.dp)

    ) {
        mappedReceipts.forEach { rcpt ->
            item {
                Text(
                    text = rcpt.key,
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .padding(top = 16.dp)
                        .padding(bottom = 8.dp)
                )
            }
            Card(
                elevation = 4.dp
            ) {
                items(rcpt.value.size) { lazyItemScope ->
                    ReceiptItem(
                        rcpt.value[lazyItemScope],
                        cardType = getCardType(lazyItemScope, rcpt.value.size),
                    ) {
                        navController.navigate(
                            ReceiptFragmentDirections.actionReceiptFragment2ToReceiptDetailsFragment2(
                                it
                            )
                        )
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want to add a card because if I add card side items for each item then there is the line shown at the bottom after every card due to elevation but I want to use elevation for the whole grouped list card, not for every item.

Comment: you should set this elevation on your LazyColumn or wrapping Card inside item and iterate  rcpt and add items inside it. actually the second way is not good solution

Comment: @VahidGarousi actually the item should not be inside the card or any elevation it would be a normal text so only items should be shown elevated or inside a card.

Comment: can you send a image of your actual and expected result?